# Restrict while adding item to has_many collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

According to rails guide raising an exception in the before_add block for has many will prevent the object getting added to the collection. But however the exception raise is not handled by active_record.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :before_add => :check_credit_limit

  def check_credit_limit(order)
     #If a before_add callback throws an exception, the object does not get added to the collection. 
     raise 'Value cannot be greater than 450' if order.value > 450
  end
end

Failure/Error: customer.orders << order
value cannot be greater than 450
```

How can i handle this gracefully?

Comment: y are u not validating on `order` model ??

Comment: yes I can do it in the order model but for the other scenarios like
`raise 'value cannot be greater than 450' if the order.value > 450 and self.type == 'Normal'`, I am not able to handle the exception gracefully

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you raise an exception, you'll need to handle it yourself and figure out how to rescue it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the validation on the order class:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_value_limit

  def check_value_limit
    errors.add(:value, "can not be greater than 450") if value > 450
  end
end
```

OR as an example for marc's comment above, you'll have to add the error to your object and handle the exception manually.  This is a basic example of handling on a create.

update your validation method to add the error to the object:

customer.rb

```
  def check_credit_limit(order)
     #If a before_add callback throws an exception, the object does not get added to the collection.
     if order.value > 450
       errors.add(:base, "Value can not be greater than 450")
       raise 'Value cannot be greater than 450'
     end 
  end
```

an example of handling the exception on create in your controller:

```
def create
  @customer.new(params[:customer])
  if @customer.save
    …
  else
   render :action=>"new"
  end
rescue
  render :action=>"new"
end
```

You may want to add a custom exception type and rescue from it specifically so any other exceptions will still be thrown correctly.